What is going on with SEDE (and SO)? Can it be used only after the weekly update ends?
It seems that at the moment:

After clicking on compose query you get: "Server Error in '/' Application. - Runtime Error". But it works if you use a different site instead of SO.
Running any SEDE query on SO returns an error: "Line 65536: Cannot open database "StackOverflow" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'STACKEXCHANGE\svc_sede'."
Here is a very simple query, just to serve as a quick test - you can check that it returns an error on SO but it runs on a different site. You can also try this on rene's query checking the progress of the database update. It fails on SO.
When the same query is run on another site, the result suggest that the database update is running at the moment. IIRC in the past it was possible to use SEDE during the update.


given we have two _Temp databases https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1849746 I'm sure the refresh  is stuck. Needs an sre to diagnose and fix.

not sure why stackoverflow is in the state it is but mathoverflow is refreshing since 00:29 utc https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1849747 so I guess that is the one that needs to be fixed first. SO seems to be collateral damage.

Looks like it's status-completed, was fixed by a silent developer 6-8 hours after being reported.
